# Dynamic sqlite column alias

Tags: sqlite

I am doing something like this:

```
SELECT date('now');
```

And it will give me a result set like this:

```
date('now')
-----------
2015-05-16
```

What I want to be able to do is alias the `date('now')` to the evaluated expression, `2015-05-16`, so my result would look like this:

```
2015-05-16
-----------
2015-05-16
```

If I just try

```
SELECT date('now') as date('now');
```

That won't work. From what I can see in the documentation that is by design. Is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date('now') as date('now');
```

That won't work.

---

Of course, it won't work.

An alias can't be a **function**.
It has to be a **name**.

Like so:

```
SELECT date('now') AS dateNow;
```